# При обновлении через AJAX курсор теряет фокус

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть функция, которая каждые 10 секунд через `$.post` запрашивает обновление информации.

И если в этот момент курсор находится в форме (в `<textarea>` или `<input>`), то данный курсор слетает с формы.

Кто-то сталкивался с таким?

Comment: ну, добавьте в success Вашего аякса принудительный фокус тому элементу, который Вам нужен

Comment: По идее так быть вообще не должно. Самое интересное, что где-то 5-10 тысяч строк кода назад это всё работало как нужно - без слёта курсора и с обновлением. Но что-то пошло не так. )) Лепить костыли с фокусом не хочу. Нужно найти первоисточник.

Comment: Не проверил раньше, проблема оказывается в гугл.хроме. В остальных браузерах курсор не сбивается. Ну и в хроме раньше работало нормально...

Answer (score 1):

Перед запросом создавайте указатель на элемент в фокусе:

```
var focused = $(document.activeElement).attr('id');
```

По завершению запроса навешивайте фокус обратно:

```
$('#' + focused).focus();
```